# SyntaxError: net-sftp.rb:48: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT puts 'File transfer complete' in Ruby from Filezilla Client to localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, syntax-error, filezilla

I am doing Automation testing running JRuby with ConEmu to put files from my Filezila Client to my local host. It should not be to the remote server. Getting errors when I try running the below code in Ruby for establishing the connection. Transferring files here are not as important.

APOLOGIES: Will fix soon.

```
require 'net-ssh'
require 'net-sftp'
require 'dir'

local_path = 'D:\Rubynetssh'
remote_path = '/cguclaim/virtual/data/logs/gwlogs/ClaimCenter/'
file_perm = 0644
dir_perm = 0755

puts 'Connecting to remote server'
Net::SSH.start('server', 'admin', 'password1') do  |ssh|
ssh.sftp.connect do |sftp|
puts 'Checking for files which need updating'
Find.find(local_path) do |file|
  next if File.stat(file).directory?
  local_file = "#{dir}/#{file}"
  remote_file = remote_path + local_file.sub(local_path, '')

  begin
    remote_dir = File.dirname(remote_file)
    sftp.stat(remote_dir)
  rescue Net::SFTP::Operations::StatusException => e
    raise unless e.code == 2

    sftp.mkdir(remote_dir, :permissions => dir_perm)
  end

  begin
    rstat = sftp.stat(remote_file)
   rescue Net::SFTP::Operations::StatusException => e
    raise unless e.code == 2
    sftp.put_file(local_file, remote_file)
    sftp.setstat(remote_file, :permissions => file_perm)
    next
  end

  if File.stat(local_file).mtime > Time.at(rstat.mtime)
    puts "Copying #{local_file} to #{remote_file}"
    sftp.put_file(local_file, remote_file)
  end
   end
      end 

  puts 'Disconnecting from remote server'
   end

  puts 'File transfer complete'
```

When I run the command below

> jruby net-sftp.rb

this results in this error syntax

> SyntaxError: net-sftp.rb:48: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT puts 'File transfer complete'

*** EDIT ***

***Now that you put in the code in the comment it comes up as error as shown below:

```
1.     LoadError: no such file to load -- net-ssh
2.     require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939
3.     require at     
4.   C:/jruby-9.0.4.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
5.     <top> at net-sftp.rb:1
```

---

Comment: Please fix your indentions first. It is so hard to check where is the block for. And notice this line of your code: `puts ‘Disconnecting from remote server'` Opening qoute is different to your end qoute.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me on the opening and closing quote - I did not notice that. I am not sure if I can indent it because it is actually all part of one code?

Comment: I don't think you `can't` indent it. Just edit your question and do a proper intentions in your code in your question. And indentions is a best practice, it is so hard to read your code without proper indentions.

Comment: okay thank you - looking into it at the moment. now when i run jruby net-sftp.rb comes up with this 
SyntaxError: net-sftp.rb:46: syntax error, unexpected kEND

Comment: Error message below showing: LoadError: no such file to load -- net-ssh
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939
  require at C:/jruby-9.0.4.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
    <top> at net-sftp.rb:1

Answer (score 0):

The following code written below worked for me better to establish the connection from Filezilla to ConEmu but now I need to get into the ClaimCenter folder to view the files if they exist or not

```
require "net/ssh"
require "net/sftp"

@hostname = "server"
@username = "admin"
@password = "password1"
@cmd = "ls -la"

res = ""
ssh = Net::SSH.start(@hostname, @username, password: @password) do |ssh|
res = ssh.exec!(@cmd)
 end

puts res
```